# In how many ways can $n$ unique books be arranged on $m$ shelves if at least one shelf is empty?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can $n$ unique books be arranged on $m$ shelves if at least one shelf is empty?

I am pretty sure that this is a question asking about objects and dividers, but I'm not sure how to get to the answer.  There are $n!$ ways to arrange the books, and at most $m-1$ usable shelves, so would this be $n!\binom{n-1}{ m}\binom{n-1}{m}$?

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of books per shelf?

Comment: No, there's no limit, you can even have all n books on one shelf because that fulfills the point that at least one shelf will be empty.

Comment: The shelves are unique too?

Comment: Then approach the problem by first finding the total number of ways to arrange them without restriction, then subtract off all the ways such that every shelf is used.

Comment: The shelves are all the same.

Comment: So would it just be n! - n choose m

Comment: @arad No. Try a few simple cases. 2 shelves. Then answer $2\times n!$ (choose a shelf, 2 poss, then $n!$ possible orders on the shelf). Now consider 3 shelves. Harder. So try 4 books. You must either put 4 on one shelf (72 ways); or 3 on one shelf and 1 on another (144 ways); or 2 on one shelf and 2 on another (72 ways), total 288=$12\times4!$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To arrange $n$ unique books on $m$ shelves, we must insert $m - 1$ dividers among the $n$ objects.  Select $m - 1$ of the $n + m - 1$ positions required for $n$ books and $m - 1$ dividers for the dividers.  Then arrange the $n$ books in the remaining $n$ positions.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1}n!$$
ways.

From these, we must subtract the number of arrangements in which every shelf is used.  If every shelf is used, no two of the $m - 1$ dividers are adjacent.

To count the number of arrangements of the $n$ books in which no shelf is empty, line up the $n$ books in some order.  This creates $n - 1$ spaces between successive books. To ensure that every shelf is used, we must choose $m - 1$ of these $n - 1$ spaces between books in which to place a divider, which can be done in 
$$n!\binom{n - 1}{m - 1}$$
ways.

Hence, the number of ways the $n$ distinct books can be arranged on $m$ shelves if at least one shelf is left empty is 
$$n!\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} - n!\binom{n - 1}{m - 1}$$

My thanks to @almagest for pointing out that if every shelf is used, the dividers cannot be placed in the first or last positions.

Comment: Not quite. The second term is wrong. You mustn't place the dividers in either of the two outer positions, so you choose $m-1$ from $n-1$, not $m-1$ from $n+1$.

Comment: I see, so first we take all the possible options of the places for objects and dividers, and then we subtract out the possibilities in which every shelf is used which would be like putting two dividers adjacent to each other.

Comment: To place $n$ books on $m$ shelves so that no shelf is empty, first place one book on each shelf, and then distribute the remaining $n-m$ books to $m$ shelves in ${n-1\choose m-1}$ ways.

Comment: @arad Putting two dividers next to each other means that there is an empty shelf.  Therefore, I subtracted those arrangements in which no two of the dividers are adjacent.

Comment: I understand, thank you so much!